# Como faço para alterar a cor do AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Coloquei no meu app onde permite mostrar o dialog para sair da aplicação, mas o dialog está preto. Queria que ele ficasse branco. Como altero o tema do `AlertDialog`?

```
@Override // SAIR DA APLICAÇÃO
public void finish() {

    if (sair) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        alerta.setTitle("Sair");

        alerta.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        alerta.setMessage("Tem certeza de que deseja sair do xxxxx")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("SIM",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                sair = false;
                                finish();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("NÃO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alerta.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        super.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Em qual Android você está testando? Além disso, mostre uma captura de tela com esse diálogo.

Comment: Plabo já consegui, apenas inserir uma linha de código no que precisava para mostrar o AlertDialog branco, digo o Tema do background.

Obrigado, 

@Override
    // SAIR DA APLICAÇÃO
    public void finish() {

        if (sair) {
trecho modificado 
            **AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);**

Comment: @AnselmoCardoso se quiser você pode responder à sua própria pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para alterar as propriedades de uma [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), você deve adicionar o estilo ao construtor da caixa de diálogo:

```
alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

Desta forma, você pode criar a configuração que quiser dentro do `DialogStyle`.

```xml
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/material_blue_700</item>
</style>
```

Observe que o uso desse construtor está disponível apenas no nível [API 11+](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Comment: Show, Seamusd valeu!

Answer (score 2):

já consegui, apenas inserir uma linha de código no que precisava para mostrar o AlertDialog branco, digo o Tema do background.

Obrigado,

```
@Override // SAIR DA APLICAÇÃO
public void finish() { 
    if (sair)
    {
        //trecho modificado 
        AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    }
}
```